# Why are these two codes giving a different output? // bits.c float_i2f

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

```
/* 
 * float_i2f - Return bit-level equivalent of expression (float) x
 *   Result is returned as unsigned int, but
 *   it is to be interpreted as the bit-level representation of a
 *   single-precision floating point values.
 *   Legal ops: Any integer/unsigned operations incl. ||, &&. also if, while
 *   Max ops: 30
 *   Rating: 4
 */
unsigned float_i2f(int x) {
int sign = x & (1 << 31);
int minus = 1 << 31; 
int exp = 31;
int bias = 127;
int frac;
if (!x)
   return 0;
if (x == minus)
   return minus | ((exp + bias) << 23);
if (sign)
   x = ~x + 1;
while (!(x & minus))
{
   x <<= 1;
   exp -= 1;
}
frac = (((~minus) & x) >> 8);
if (x & 0x80 && ((frac & 1) ||((x & 0x7f) > 0)))
   frac++;
return sign + ((exp + bias) << 23) + frac;
}
```

I checked this code on driver.pl, which checks the correctness of answer.
But I found something strange.

If the last return statement becomes

```
return sign | ((exp + bias) << 23) | frac;
```

it says that this does not work, but if I change this to

```
return sign + ((exp + bias) << 23) + frac;
```

it becomes correct.

What's the difference between two codes? Why the first one doesn't work??
Please help me :(

Comment: Are you asking what the difference between a bitwise or and `+` is?

Comment: I thought if numbers are not overlapped like 0x00ff00 and 0x0000ff, then bitwise or and + should work same. But on the code it doesn't so I wonder why.

Comment: Why not print out the numbers in binary format that you have before the `return` line? It should be easy to see if you've got collisions. Have you also tried something like this?  `unsigned float_i2f(int x) {
    static_assert(sizeof(unsigned) == sizeof(float));
    float fx = static_cast<float>(x);
    unsigned rv;
    std::memcpy(&rv, &fx, sizeof(unsigned));
    return rv;
}`

Comment: I tried something like for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
  s1.append(to_string((((sign) | ((exp + bias) << 23) | frac) >> i) & 1));
 for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
  s2.append(to_string((((sign) | ((exp + bias) << 23) | frac) >> i) & 1));
 if (s1 != s2)
 {
  printf("%s\n%s\n", s1.c_str(), s2.c_str());
  exit(0);
 } but it does not show any results...

Comment: Try the function I wrote above.

Comment: I check if there's any different result from 0 to 1e9 but it showed nothing..

Comment: You should probably use `unsigned` variables for your bitwise calculations btw.

Comment: Shouldn't `frac` and the other variables be `unsigned`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem rises with large numbers. Consider for example 2<sup>25</sup> - 1 = 33554431 and its 2's complement binary representation is

```
00000001 11111111 11111111 11111111           // or --> 0 00000011 11111111111111111111111
```

After having found the exponent, the code evaluates `frac` as

```
frac = (((~minus) & x) >> 8);                 //   -->  0 00000000 11111111111111111111111
```

But it has to round this, so it performs

```
if (x & 0x80 && ((frac & 1) ||((x & 0x7f) > 0)))
    frac++;                                     // -->  0 00000001 00000000000000000000000
```

Basically we have a carry and we should increase the exponent, like we would do if we had to represent 999 as 1x10<sup>3</sup> instead of 9.99x10<sup>2</sup>. Now you can see the difference between `|` or `+`:

```
sign + ((exp + bias) << 23) + frac;              // --> 0 10011000 00000000000000000000000

sign | ((exp + bias) << 23) | frac;              // --> 0 10010111 00000000000000000000000
```